# The most Angular-y way of pre-loading data into $scope

Tags: angularjs

Portions of my application are full AJAX and some are traditional POST and reload. Getting data into `$scope` is a trivial task using `$http`, but, what about when data is available to a template during the page load (in the normal MVC way everybody knows and loves) instead of via AJAX after the fact?

Consider the following piece of code:

```
<div ng-repeat="address in addresses">
  {{ address.address1 }}
  {{ address.city }}, {{ address.state }} {{ address.zip }}
</div>
```

How would I go about loading 100 dynamically generated addresses into `$scope.addresses` without using AJAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use ng-init for your "inline" controller:

```
@model SampleViewModel
...
<div ng-controller="SampleCtrl" ng-init="adresses=@Model.AdressesList">
```

Another approach is demonstrated [here](http://xombe.com/2014/02/17/combine-angular-js-with-asp-net-mvc/):

```
<script>
  function SampleCtrl($scope){
     $scope.adresses = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
      ...
  }
</script>

<div ng-controller="SampleCtrl" ng-repeat="address in addresses">
```

Comment: Your first solution was precisely what I needed. I just converted my template variable to JSON and it worked great. Somehow I never stumbled across this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**`ng-init`** is an option by angularJS to operate on data while page loading.

Here, in your case you can implement a function and then assign those dynamic generated values into `$scope.addresses`.

```
<div ng-init="functionToAssignAddresses()">

 /* Populate your Addresses here.*/   

</div>
```

for more information you can follow documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) for `ng-init`.